# Is global transaction management needed to support dependent file system and JDBC write operations?

Tags: java, spring, file, transactions, xa

The objective:

- query for an object from the database
- write out a serialized representation of this object to a file system
- update the object stating that the file has been written
- update the database to reflect local change

Is it necessary to have a global transaction instead of only a `DataSourceTransactionManager` managed by Spring?

If a failure occurs during a write to the file system, there is no problem.  If a failure occurs during the write to the database there is now an erroneous new file created that hasn't been reflected in the database.  The file creation should be rolled back.

A possible alternative to a managed global transaction would be to write to a temporary folder and only move it if the database write is successful, otherwise purge it or ignore it.  Is this a valid solution?  Is the concept of a file system transaction even valid since it doesn't expose transactional operations like JDBC and JMS do?

Comment: which os and which filesystem is this?

Comment: @steve, this would be on an NTFS share.  I ended up using AOP transaction syncronization and `after-commit` handler to solve this problem (I think so.. it was at my previous employer 4 months ago)